# Create multiple rectangular borders within single entry widget in Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, widget

I currently have a Tkinter GUI with the following layout:

[image]

I would like to create multiple rectangular borders within my upper entry widget, so it would look like this:

[image]

Is there any way to do this?

Currently my code looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python


from sys import exit
from Tkinter import *
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from time import sleep
from os.path import exists
import os, time, sys, ttk

#Initialize Tkinter by creating Tk root widget, which is a window with a
Root = Tk()
Root.title("GUI TOOL")

class Command:
    def __init__(self, func, *args, **kw):
        self.func = func
        self.args = args
        self.kw = kw
    def __call__(self, *args, **kw):
        args = self.args+args
        kw.update(self.kw)
        self.func(*args, **kw)


    ##Script definitions
 def quitter():
     exit(0)

 ##Button organization and layout


 Sub0 = Frame(Root)

 ###Define X mesh node
 Sub = Frame(Sub0)

 #X mesh node
 Label(Sub, text = "Create X mesh nodes").grid(row = 0, column = 1)

 #X min text box area
 v1=StringVar()

 #Create entry widget to get user input, in this case a text string for the
 X min, label min below entry widget box in appropriate column

 Entry(Sub, textvariable=v1).grid(row=1, column=1)
 Label(Sub, text = "min").grid(row=1, column=0)

 #X max text box area
 v2=StringVar()

 #Create entry widget to get user input, in this case a text string for the
 #X max, label max below entry widget box in appropriate column

 Entry(Sub, textvariable=v2).grid(row=2, column=1)
 Label(Sub, text = "max").grid(row=2, column=0)

 #X step text box area
 v3=StringVar()

 #Create entry widget to get user input, in this case a text string for the
 #X step increment, label step increment below entry widget box in 
 #appropriate column

 Entry(Sub, textvariable=v3).grid(row=3, column=1)
 Label(Sub, text = "step increment").grid(row=3, column=0, ipady = 5)

 #Define line between X mesh node definitions and Y mesh node definitions
 Sub.pack(side = TOP)

 ##Define Y mesh node

 #Y mesh node
 Label(Sub, text = "Create Y mesh nodes").grid(row = 0, column=3)

 #Y min text box area
 v4=StringVar()

 #Create entry widget to get user input, in this case a text string for the
 #Y min, label min below entry widget box in appropriate column

 Entry(Sub, textvariable=v4).grid(row=1, column=3, ipadx = 5)
 Label(Sub, text = "min").grid(row=1, column=2, ipadx = 5)

 #Y max text box area
 v5=StringVar()

 #Create entry widget to get user input, in this case a text string for the 
 #Y max, label max below entry widget box in appropriate column

 Entry(Sub, textvariable=v5).grid(row=2, column=3, ipadx = 5)
 Label(Sub, text = "max").grid(row=2, column=2, ipadx = 5)

 #Y step text box area
 v6=StringVar()

 #Create entry widget to get user input, in this case a text string for the 
 #Y step increment, label step increment below entry widget box in 
 #appropriate column

 Entry(Sub, textvariable=v6).grid(row=3, column=3, ipadx = 5)
 Label(Sub, text = "step increment").grid(row=3, column=2, ipady = 5, ipadx 
 = 5)

 #Define line between X mesh node definitions and Y mesh node definitions
 Sub.pack(side = TOP)


 #Define Z mesh noe

 #Z mesh node
 Label(Sub, text = "Create Z mesh nodes").grid(row = 0, column = 5)

 #Z min text box area
 v7=StringVar()

 #Create entry widget to get user input, in this case a text string for the
 #Z min, label min below entry widget box in appropriate column

 Entry(Sub, textvariable=v7).grid(row=1, column=5, ipadx = 5)
 Label(Sub, text = "min").grid(row=1, column=4, ipadx = 5)

 #Z max text box area
 v8=StringVar()

 #Create entry widget to get user input, in this case a text string for the
 Z max, label max below entry widget box in appropriate column

 Entry(Sub, textvariable=v8).grid(row=2, column=5, ipadx = 5)
 Label(Sub, text = "max").grid(row=2, column=4, ipadx = 5)

 #Z step text box area
 v9=StringVar()

 #Create entry widget to get user input, in this case a text string for the
 #Z step increment, label step increment below entry widget box in 
 #appropriate column

 Entry(Sub, textvariable=v9).grid(row=3, column=5, ipadx = 5)
 Label(Sub, text = "step increment").grid(row=3, column=4, ipady = 5, ipadx
  = 5)

  #Define line between Z mesh node definitions and Mesh button definitions
  Sub.pack(side = TOP)
  Frame(Sub0,height=2, relief = GROOVE, bg="black").pack(side = TOP, fill = 
  BOTH, pady= 5)


  ###Define Mesh Interval buttons
  Sub3 = Frame(Sub0)
  #Generate Evenly Spaced Mesh Button
  Button(Sub3, text = "Generate Evenly Sampled Interval Mesh").grid(row=10, 
  column = 0, ipady = 2) 

 #Generate Geometrically Spaced Mesh Button
 Button(Sub3, text = "Generate Geometrically Sampled Interval 
 Mesh").grid(row=11, column = 0, ipady = 2)

 #Generate Irregularly Spaced Mesh Button
 Button(Sub3, text = "Generate Irregularly Sampled Interval 
 Mesh").grid(row=12, column = 0, ipady = 2)

 #Define line between Mesh buttons and Quit button
 Sub3.pack(side = TOP)
 Frame(Sub0,height=2, relief = GROOVE, bg="black").pack(side = TOP, fill = 
 BOTH, pady= 5)


 ##GUI organization and quit button 


 Sub0.pack(side = TOP, padx = 10)
 Button(Root, text = "Quit", command = quitter).pack(side = BOTTOM, pady = 
 5)

 #The window will not appear until we enter the Tkinter event loop. Script

 Root.mainloop()
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to just pack these in a frame, set the background color to "black" and give the frame `padx` and `pady`

Comment: I'm not seeing how this would work. I was able to color the entry widget's background but not add the square borders...

Comment: I am able to create the border around the entire entry widget but not in between the entries using: Sub.configure(bd = 2, relief = GROOVE, padx = 15, pady = 10). Recall in the question I said that I have one entry widget for the entire upper portion of my GUI.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer to "how do I put a frame around a group of widgets" is to use a frame widget, and put those inner widgets inside that frame. In this case you could make one frame for "Create X mesh nodes", one for "Create Y mesh nodes", and one for "Create Z mesh nodes"

Since the contents of these frames are essentially identical (same number of labels and entries), they should line up nicely.

Another choice would be to put all of those labels and entries into a single frame, and set the color of that frame to "black". Then, with proper use of padding options, you can arrange it so that the background color bleeds through between the groups.

---

pro tip: if you group all of your layout commands together instead of combining widget creation and widget layout, these sorts of changes become *much* easier, and the code is arguably much easier to understand.

For example, instead of this:

```
Entry(Sub, textvariable=v2).grid(row=2, column=1)
Label(Sub, text = "max").grid(row=2, column=0)
...
Entry(Sub, textvariable=v3).grid(row=3, column=1)
Label(Sub, text = "step increment").grid(row=3, column=0, ipady = 5)
...
```

Do it like this:

```
e1 = Entry(Sub, textvariable=v2)
e2 = Entry(Sub, textvariable=v3)
...
l1 = Label(Sub, text = "step increment")
l2 = Label(Sub, text = "max")
...
e1.grid(row=2, column=1)
l1..grid(row=2, column=0)
e2.grid(row=3, column=1)
l2.grid(row=3, column=0, ipady = 5)
```

Comment: I had previously put the X mesh nodes in one frame Sub, and the Y mesh nodes in one frame Sub1, and the Z mesh nodes in one frame Sub2, but I wasn't able to get them to line up easily using the grid option, so I combined them into one frame Sub. I could see how doing what I want to do now would be easy if I had left them as separate frames. How would I line them up in the same way if they were in separate frames? Thanks for the pro tip!

Comment: Alternatively you mention if they were in the same frame already (which they are), then with the proper padx and pady options I could arrange it so the background color bleeds through between the groups. I had previously tried Sub.configure(bd = 2, relief = GROOVE, padx = 15, pady = 10) but this didn't seem to work as it filled the entire background of the frame. Ideas?